# How to use `nix-env --set` without losing access to `nix-env`?

Tags: nix

If I create a derivation using nix and then run `nix-env --set <derivation name>`, then commands like `nix-env` and `nix` are now missing from my nix profile and so I get the error `Command 'nix-env' not found`. I then have to mess around with symlinks in my nix profile to get it back.

This of course makes sense, because the `nix` package itself is not part of my derivation. Is there a way that I can use `nix-env --set` without losing access to nix itself?

Comment: `nix-shell --pure` might be what you're looking for?